# Group by LINQ vs group by SQL

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have the following query in SQL which I would like to convert to LINQ statement.

```
select AreaId, BrandId, MilestoneId, DocumentCategoryId
from Document
group by AreaId, Brandid, MilestoneId, DocumentCategoryId
```

I have tried, e.g.,

```
var docs =
    from d in documents
    group d by new
    {
        d.Area,
        d.Brand,
        d.MilestoneId,
        d.DocumentCategoryId
    } into gcs
    select new Group()
    {
        Area = gcs.Key.Area,
        Brand = gcs.Key.Brand,
        MilestoneId = gcs.Key.MilestoneId,
        DocumentCategoryId = gcs.Key.DocumentCategoryId,
    };
```

And

```
var docs = documents
    .GroupBy(d => new Group
    {
        Area = d.Area,
        Brand = d.Brand,
        MilestoneId = d.MilestoneId,
        DocumentCategoryId = d.DocumentCategoryId,
    })
```

but the result in SQL returns 88 rows (the aim), in query syntax 78 rows and in LINQ 270 (total number).

I would like a LINQ statement for to return 88 rows.

Comment: Why are you using a groupby; if you're only interested in the **key** and not the aggregate entries that belong to the key? Is there a reason you're not using `Distinct` as opposed to `GroupBy`? (both in SQL and in code)

Comment: is the data in a database?  if so what's wrong with using sql and offloading the fetch to the db-server?  It's a very bad idea if you're going to load all the data into memory just because you want to use linq.

Comment: @Rob assuming that `documents` is a `Table<Document>` / `DbSet<Document>` or similar: it doesn't load "all the data" - it loads all the unique combinations - although I agree with Flater that if there isn't an aggregate, Distinct would be more "obvious"

Comment: @Flater you are right, when did change by Marc and looked at actual SQL it was translated to distinct. There is no reason for grouping, thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I expect the *final version* is essentially switching to LINQ-to-Objects - i.e. populating a `Group` *object* per row, then grouping in .NET terms, which will mean one row per group as I doubt your `Group` implements the right patterns for equality. To get LINQ to treat the last version correctly, you probably need to add an anonymous type into the mix (LINQ understands this should behave like a tuple):

```
var docs = documents
    .GroupBy(d => new
    {
        Area = d.Area,
        Brand = d.Brand,
        MilestoneId = d.MilestoneId,
        DocumentCategoryId = d.DocumentCategoryId,
    }).Select(grp => new Group {
        Area = grp.Key.Area,
        Brand = grp.Key.Brand,
        MilestoneId = grp.Key.MilestoneId,
        DocumentCategoryId = grp.Key.DocumentCategoryId,
    });
```

As for the 88 vs 78: have you looked at what SQL is being issued? That should tell you what it is doing differently.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. And this indeed was translated to distinct when looking at actual SQL query sent out.